Sharing a Folder in QEMU/KVM with Ubuntu 24.04 Host and Ubuntu 16.04 VM
I'm having trouble mounting a shared folder in my Ubuntu 16.04 VM to share with an Ubuntu 24.04 host using QEMU/KVM and Virt-Manager.
I've been following the instructions that almost every guidance article and video has shown, which is to enable shared memory, and then add a new filesystem hardware in Virt-Manager with settings similar to the one below:
Virt-Manager Share Folder Settings
After doing this, we are to go into the VM and run the following command:
sudo mount -t virtiofs share /home/foo/share
When I try to do this, I get the following error inside the Ubuntu 16.04 VM:
mount: unknown filesystem type: 'virtiofs'
I know there is also the option in the filesystem settings to use virtio-9p instead of virtiofs, but that renders my VM unbootable.
I have yet to come across a single guidance video or article that demonstrates this error inside the VM of not recognizing virtiofs. It looks like this filesystem is not available in the Ubuntu 16.04 repo, but it is on the Ubuntu 24.04 repo. Is 16.04 simply too old for virtiofs? If the solution is using virtio-9p, why would my VM become unbootable with this setting?

Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-Of-Life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu. Please upgrade to a supported release. See https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/

It's not Ubuntu 16.04 being too old, it's the kernel version that's the problem. According to the virtiofs webpage - https://virtio-fs.gitlab.io - it became available with the 5.4 kernel release. While you can probably get a 5.4 kernel installed on Ubuntu 16, I think your best bet is to setup NFS file-sharing, which will definitely work on all of your systems.
